# Создание шорткода только на одной странице

Tags: php, wordpress

В файле `functions.php` определён шорткод с помощью `add_shortcode`. Там же подключается js-скрипт для этого шорткода с помощью хука `wp_enqueue_scripts`. И получается, что этот шорткод и js-скрипт будут подключаться на всех страницах.
Этот шорткод вместе с js-скриптом нужен только на одной странице.
Как можно создать этот шорткод только на нужной странице?
т.е. чтобы не выполнялся лишний код шорткода при формировании всех страниц

Comment: За что заминусовали, граждане? Хороший вопрос, кстати. Поставил свой плюс, чтобы уравновесить.

Comment: @KAGGDesign поддержу

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Функции определения страницы работают начиная с определённого момента. Поэтому ваш код надо повесить на какой-то хук, например, на `wp_enqueue_scripts`:

```
function cool_shortcode_callback( $atts ) {
    return 'cool';
}

function my_wp_enqueue_scripts() {
    $allowed_pages = [
        'about',
        'contact',
    ];
    if ( is_page( $allowed_pages ) ) {
        add_shortcode( 'cool_shortcode', 'cool_shortcode_callback' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'cool-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/cool.js', [ 'jquery' ], '1.0', true );
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_wp_enqueue_scripts' );
```

Comment: подскажите, почему не работает ajax, который определён только на одной странице. т.е. дополнил немного ваш код, добавил в вопрос

Comment: т.е. функции `cool_shortcode_callback и create_payment_form` а также `wp_ajax_` определены по событию `wp_enqueue_scripts`, в результате ajax не работает

Comment: разве нельзя эти  функции `cool_shortcode_callback и create_payment_form` определить только на нужных страницах?

Comment: И как, интересно? Использование вложенных функций, как у вас, - очень плохая практика в php. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18256770/why-is-it-a-good-idea-to-avoid-nested-blocks-in-a-function-php

Comment: ajax не будет работать так, как вы написали. хуки должны быть объявлены прямо в function.php. Если очень интересно, задайте отдельный вопрос, я распишу, что там происходит в коде ядра.

Comment: И вообще, так лучше не делать - вы изменили суть вопроса последней правкой. После чего мой ответ уже не в тему, или почти не в тему. Вы запутываете людей, которые могут искать ответ на похожий вопрос. Верните, пожалуста, вопрос к исходному состоянию.

Comment: ок, вернул изначальный вариант. создал отдельную тему, не затруднит подсказать?